# Format text list with corresponding key into spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, libreoffice-calc

I have a text file with dates arranged as such.

```
name1
2010-01-02 (i)
2010-05-07 (i)
2010-06-12 (i)
name2
2010-01-02 (i)
2010-05-07 (i)
2010-06-12 (i)
name3
2011-01-05 (i)
2011-05-05 (i)
2011-06-14 (i)
```

Is there a function or way to arrange the data in a spreadsheet with 2 columns like:

```
+---------------+-----+
| 2010-01-02 (i)|name1|
| 2010-05-07 (i)|name1|
| 2010-06-12 (i)|name1|  
| 2010-01-02 (i)|name2|
| 2010-05-07 (i)|name2|
| 2010-06-12 (i)|name2|
| 2011-01-05 (i)|name3|
| 2011-05-05 (i)|name3|
| 2011-06-14 (i)|name3|
+---------------+-----+
```

So the items can be sorted and counted?

**Edit**
I believe I need to write a macro that can loop through column A

1. !if "()"
2. cut cell
3. else paste cell B

Comment: I've cobbled together something that works in LibreOffice.  It's nowhere near elegant, but it does seem to work if one assumes column A in your spreadsheet is your data as above and there are no other contents.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in column A of Sheet1, the following will do the trick:

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBAModule
Option VBASupport 1
Option Explicit
Sub rearrange()
    Dim elements As Integer, rowIndex As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim Name As String
'   LO Basic additions
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    dim cell as object
    Doc = ThisComponent
    Sheet = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")

    Cell = Sheet.getCellRangeByName("D1")

    Cell.formula = "=COUNTA(A1:A104586)"

    elements = cell.value
    rowIndex = 1
    For i = 1 To elements
        If Right(Range("A" & i), 3) <> "(i)" Then
            Name = Range("A" & i)
        Else
            Range("B" & rowIndex) = Name
            Range("C" & rowIndex) = Range("A" & i)
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume this is LO Basic code? When I attached the macro to a button and clicked it, I got this error: `Basic Runtime error. Object variable not set.` Pointer was on `elements` line.

Comment: Sorry - it's VBA, not LO Basic.  I hadn't noticed the LO tag until after I built the VBA.  Any chance LO can deal with it?  If not, I can try to figure out the LO version, but not until later in the week.

Comment: I read that LO Basic is similar syntax that requires minimal changes. Figured your code was VBA when I saw `xlDown`.